# append dictionary, save to a file and increment dictionary regularly

Tags: python

I create a dictionary and save it to a file using json. The code takes input and updates the dictionary regularly, but unfortunately I can't get it to write the dictionary properly. 
Following is the code that I have written. Have a look in here :

```
import os, sys, pickle, re, json
from optparse import OptionParser

parser = OptionParser("Store Daily Intakes \n python [Options] <-h help>")
parser.add_option("-n", "--ndays", dest="ndays", action="store", type="int", help="Input the day")
parser.add_option("-m", "--morning", dest="morning", action="store", type="string", help="Input the morning intake format <Banana-1pc,Bread-1pc,CottageChees-2tbs>")
parser.add_option("-l", "--lunch", dest="lunch", action="store", type="string", help="Input the Lunch intake format <Rice-2tbs,Roti-1pc,ChickenCurry-2tbs,Dal-2tbs>")
parser.add_option("-a", "--afternoon", dest="afternoon", action="store", type="string", help="Input the afternoon intake format <Cornflakes-2tbs,Banana-1pc>")
parser.add_option("-d", "--dinner", dest="dinner", action="store", type="string", help="Input the dinner intake format <Pasta-20gms, Cheese-2slice>")

(options, args) = parser.parse_args()

if options.ndays is None or options.morning is None or options.lunch is None or options.afternoon is None or options.dinner is None :
   print parser.print_help()
   exit(-1)


if os.path.isfile("./DailyInTakeFile.json") is True :

    jout = file('./DailyInTakeFile.json','r') # read mode
    CurDct = json.load(jout)
    print CurDct

    DailyInTake = dict()
    DailyInTake["%d" % options.ndays] = {}
    din = DailyInTake["%s" % options.ndays]
    din['Morning'] = options.morning
    din['Lunch'] = options.lunch
    din['Afternoon'] = options.afternoon
    din['Dinner'] = options.dinner

    saved = sys.stdout
    ofile = file('DailyInTakeFile.json', 'a') # append mode

    for idx in CurDct.keys() :
        if int(idx) == options.ndays :
            print idx, options.ndays
            print "The Intake for day # %d exists" %options.ndays
            print "Are you sure you want to overwrite: Type [yes/no]"
            lett=sys.stdin.read()
            if "yes" in lett :
                CurDct[idx]['Morning'] = options.morning
                CurDct[idx]['Lunch'] = options.lunch
                CurDct[idx]['Afternoon'] = options.afternoon
                CurDct[idx]['Dinner'] = options.dinner
                ofile.close()
                sys.exit("Exiting after updating day # %d" % options.ndays)
            else :
                ofile.close()
                sys.exit("Exiting without update")

        else :
            sys.stdout = ofile
            print json.dumps(DailyInTake)
            print ","
            sys.stdout = saved
            ofile.close()

else :
    DailyInTake = dict()
    DailyInTake["%d" % options.ndays] = {}
    din = DailyInTake["%s" % options.ndays]
    din['Morning'] = options.morning
    din['Lunch'] = options.lunch
    din['Afternoon'] = options.afternoon
    din['Dinner'] = options.dinner

   #print DailyInTake

    saved = sys.stdout
    ofile = file('DailyInTakeFile.json', 'a') # append mode
    sys.stdout = ofile
    print json.dumps(DailyInTake)
    print ","
    sys.stdout = saved
    ofile.close()


from datetime import date, timedelta
from subprocess import call
call("cp DailyInTakeFile.json DailyInTakeFile.json.%s" % str(date.today()), shell=True)
```

The output json file from this code is the following for example :

```
{"1": {"Lunch": "l3", "Dinner": "d3", "Afternoon": "a3", "Morning": "m3"}}
{"2": {"Lunch": "l3", "Dinner": "d3", "Afternoon": "a3", "Morning": "m3"}}
```

As you can see it is just adding a single dictionary each time rather than appending to the first one created. I just can't think it out anymore. Any help will be appreciated.

---

UPDATE WITH CODE THAT MAINLY CHANGED

---

```
 saved = sys.stdout
    for idx in CurDct.keys() :
        if int(idx) == options.ndays :
            print idx, options.ndays
            print "The Intake for day # %d exists" %options.ndays
            print "Are you sure you want to overwrite: Type [yes/no]"
            lett=sys.stdin.read()
            if "yes" in lett :
                ofile = file('DailyInTakeFile.json', 'w') # write mode
                sys.stdout = ofile
                CurDct.update(DailyInTake)
                print json.dumps(CurDct)
                sys.stdout = saved
                ofile.close()
                sys.exit("Exiting after updating day # %d" % options.ndays)
            else :
                sys.exit("Exiting without update")

        else :
            ofile = file('DailyInTakeFile.json', 'w') # write mode
            sys.stdout = ofile
            CurDct.update(DailyInTake)
            print json.dumps(CurDct)
            sys.stdout = saved
            ofile.close()
```

Comment: SO questions should be self-contained.  Optimally, code should be reduced to the minimal example exhibiting the problem and included in the question.

Comment: The code seems lengthy, but actually is not that difficult for the experts to have a quick view. As you mentioned, I could try the shelve module.

Comment: We just have certain policies on SO, see e.g. [Questions linking to external web sites instead of showing code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code) and [Auto-ban questions that use pastebin?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94807/auto-ban-questions-that-use-pastebin) for details.  People have agreed that we want questions to be self-contained.  I'm not complaining to you – I simply want to point out the rules, and encourage you to update your question accordingly.

Comment: Understood. As the code was a bit lengthy I didn't post it here, I could do that now.

Comment: The general idea is to make questions as useful as possible for people who search this site later.  Of course your primary aim is to get your question answered, but by putting a tiny bit of effort in your question you can also help future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the code, you create a new dictionary every time. And don't append to the old one in the file. `DailyInTake = dict()` So output to the file, just appends a new dictionary.

My suggestion would be. 
To add the new dictionary index to CurDct as `CurDct[index] = DailyInTake[index]`, then dump the whole dictionary back to the file. You can open the file for writing other than appending.

Comment: I modified the code and that seems to give me what I expected. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Using JSON serialisation as a mutable data storage backend seems like a rather odd solution.  Without looking at your code in detail, I suggest using one of the solutions that are *meant* to be used this way.  The most suitable one for this case seems to be the [`shelve`](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html) module.